# Open .exe on remote computer with Power Shell

Tags: powershell, exe, remote-desktop, invoke-command

I have .exe with location C:\Program Files (x86)\Intercede\MyIDDesktop

I want to create script to open it on remote computer.

When I execute script:

```
invoke-command -computername {start-process -filepath C:\Program Files (x86)\Intercede\MYIDDesktop\MYIDDesktop.exe}
```

I receive parameter error.

Where I have made mistakes?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual (complete) error message you get.  Regardless of that: You could try to think about how cmdlets in Powershell deal with parameter values with spaces in it.  ;-)  ... and you should read the complete help for the cmdlets you use ... **including the examples** to learn how to use them.

Comment: There is no compitername defined in your example - i assume you left this out not to expose the machine name. But - just in case. Here's a reminder. :)

Answer (score 3):

If PowerShell remoting has not been enabled, and you are not an admin on the remote host, you cannot use Invoke-Command.

As noted, you have not given a computername, so this would never work anyway.

Secondly, anything with spaces must be properly quoted. See the help for about quoting or other web articles on the topic. For example:

> [Quoting specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules%20https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting)

Lastly, as Olaf is pointing out, this is really PowerShell beginner stuff, and that means you really should spend some time getting ramped up. Hop over to Youtube and search for 'beginning Powershell', intermediate PowerShell', 'advanced PowerShell', and etc... and you'll get lots of details to practice with. Use and master the help files.

Anyway... Essentially, your one line should be something like this...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'SomeRemoteComputerName' -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -filepath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intercede\MYIDDesktop\MYIDDesktop.exe'} -Credential 'WhateverCredsNeededIfYourLoggedOnSessionDoesNotHaveAdminPermissionsOnTheRemoteTarget'
```

> [get function / cmdlet details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6)

```
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-Command).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Invoke-Command -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-Command -Online
Get-help -Name Invoke-Command -Examples
```

Even with the aforementioned, there is more to running 'exe' on remote systems, relative a given use case, which you have not specified as well.

Comment: Is it possible to open this on remote computer so user doesn't have to enter credentials? Have googled this, did not find solution.

Comment: As documented, Powershell will always run code in the context of the user who started the session an ran the script. You cannot natively run PowerShell code in teh context a currently logged on remote user.  You have to use 3rdP tools for that. Lastly, no, if code requires auth, the user running the session must provide it, or you use a scheduled task, configured on the remote host, with the require credentials to run the code.